# Bulding Dataframe with additional entries from existing one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so -

```
df:
 SAMPLE_ID ROW COL  LAB_L  LAB_A  LAB_B 
     0      1   1   1  61.41 -24.27 -50.02
     1      2   1   2  61.79 -23.91 -49.86
     2      3   1   3  61.55 -24.08  -50.1
     3      4   1   4  61.75 -23.77 -49.98
     4      5   1   5  61.61 -24.06  -50.3
```

What I'd like is a dataframe with triple the entries, one for each LAB.

In this case, I would want -

```
 SAMPLE_ID ROW COL  Value  Field 
     0      1   1   61.41   LAB_L
     0      1   1   -24.27  LAB_A
     0      1   1   -50.02  LAB_B
     1      2   1   61.79   LAB_L
     1      2   1   -23.91  LAB_A
     1      2   1   -49.86  LAB_B
     ....
```

Would really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `melt` function:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.melt(df, id_vars=['SAMPLE_ID', 'ROW', 'COL'], var_name='Field', value_name='Value')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create three copies of your initial dataframe, then drop two columns in each, i.e. df_1 would have cols=[SAMPLE_ID, ROW COL, LAB_L], df_2 would have cols =[SAMPLE_ID, ROW COL, LAB_A], etc. You could then rename the LAB_* column to Value and then add a Field column with the respective lab name. Finally you can merge these three data frames together.